# automatically set field values for models in Django

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to automatically set field values for models in Django when defining the model?
I need t define some values of fields automatically in my model using function.
my function get input image path calculate and I need that calculation results to define my database fields in Django.

first to I want is something like this :

my view :

```
def myview(request):
    uploadimages = UploadImagesForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if uploadimages.is_valid():
        # Get the images that have been browsed
        if request.FILES.get('multipleimages', None) is not None:
            images = request.FILES.getlist('multipleimages')
            for image in images:
                MyModel.objects.create(field1=request.user,field2=image)
```

that doesn't work because to work my function need first to upload image in server to get the path to work.

any idea how to define my model automate using my function ?

**update**

```
instance = MyModel.objects.create(user=request.user, upload=image)
                instance.field1 = name
                instance.field2 = myvalue
                instance.field3 = myvalue2
                instance.field4  = myvalue3
                instance.field5  = myvalue4
                instance.save()
```

error in this code is the my function cant understand the image path to create the calculation to set the values in fields.

if I use this :

```
MyModel.objects.create(user=request.user, upload=image)
instance = MyModel.objects.create(user=request.user, upload=image)
                instance.field1 = name
                instance.field2 = myvalue
                instance.field3 = myvalue2
                instance.field4  = myvalue3
                instance.field5  = myvalue4
                instance.save()
```

that work but create me duplicates in database .

Comment: `.create()` method is creating a record in database without `.save()` method. Just define `instance = MyModel(user=request.user, upload=image)`, other fields and then call `.save()`. In this way, you avoid the problem of duplicating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```py
instance = MyModel.objects.create(field1=request.user, field2=image)
instance.field3 = myfunc(image)
instance.field4 = myfunc(image)
instance.save()
```

Comment: ok but is the same just replace my `MyModel.objects.create` with your code

Comment: and remove old code, please, leave only clear new code

Comment: you try override your real code for the question, so we have an trouble with the understanding, double creating can be the solution, may be you can show real code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153171/discussion-between-bear-brown-and-chris-papas).

Comment: look create it for any image upload double insert in my database first  insert  is complete,all fields is correct(that mean work my function) and the second insert have only the path (field2=image) and all others fields is empty..help this ?

Comment: lets go to chat